# Create a Database out of a multidimensional JSON file (Api get request)

Tags: python, json, database, sqlite

I'm pretty new to python and databases.

I am looking for a easy way to store a big chunk of data to a Database with Python. I make an API get request and get back data that looks like this:

I would like to work with sqlite3 but different approaches are also possible.
**Data**

```
{
"Paging": {
    "Page": 1,
    "TotalPages": 1014,
    "TotalRows": 50663,
    "PageSize": 50
},
"ErrorMessage": null,
"ErrorCode": 0,
"Data": [
    {
        "RebateDifference": 0.00,
        "ShippingIds": [],
        "AcceptLossOfReturnRight": false,
        "Id": "1689753813076",
        "OrderNumber": "#1001",
        "State": 3,
        "VatMode": 0,
        "CreatedAt": "2019-09-20T11:10:35",
        "ShippedAt": "2019-09-20T11:10:36",
        "ConfirmedAt": null,
        "PayedAt": "2019-09-20T11:32:32",
        "SellerComment": null,
        "Comments": [],
        "InvoiceNumberPrefix": "",
        "InvoiceNumberPostfix": null,
        "InvoiceNumber": 1286,
        "InvoiceDate": "2019-11-11T00:00:00",
        "InvoiceAddress": {
            "BillbeeId": 79813530,
            "FirstName": "Name",
            "LastName": "Lastname",
            "Company": "",
            "NameAddition": null,
            "Street": "street",
            "HouseNumber": "73a",
            "Zip": "76137",
            "City": "Karlsruhe",
            "CountryISO2": "DE",
            "Country": "DE",
            "Line2": "",
            "Email": "Mail@gmail.com",
            "State": "",
            "Phone": null
        },
        "ShippingAddress": {
            "BillbeeId": 79813530,
            "FirstName": "Name",
            "LastName": "Name",
            "Company": "",
            "NameAddition": null,
            "Street": "street",
            "HouseNumber": "73a",
            "Zip": "76137",
            "City": "Karlsruhe",
            "CountryISO2": "DE",
            "Country": "DE",
            "Line2": "",
            "Email": "mail@gmail.com",
            "State": "",
            "Phone": null
        },
        "PaymentMethod": 31,
        "ShippingCost": 0.0,
        "TotalCost": 31.90,
        "AdjustmentCost": 0.0,
        "AdjustmentReason": null,
        "OrderItems": [
            {
                "BillbeeId": 143336888,
                "TransactionId": "3760601071700",
                "Product": {
                    "OldId": null,
                    "Id": null,
                    "Title": "title",
                    "Weight": null,
                    "SKU": null,
                    "SkuOrId": null,
                    "IsDigital": null,
                    "Images": null,
                    "EAN": null,
                    "PlatformData": null,
                    "TARICCode": null,
                    "CountryOfOrigin": null,
                    "BillbeeId": null
                },
                "Quantity": 1.000,
                "TotalPrice": 31.90000000000,
                "TaxAmount": 5.093277310924369747899159664,
                "TaxIndex": 1,
                "Discount": 0.0000,
                "Attributes": [
                    {
                        "Id": "xx",
                        "Name": "",
                        "Value": null,
                        "Price": 0.0
                    }
                ],
                "GetPriceFromArticleIfAny": false,
                "IsCoupon": false,
                "ShippingProfileId": null,
                "DontAdjustStock": false,
                "UnrebatedTotalPrice": 31.9000000,
                "SerialNumber": null
            }
        ],
        "Currency": "EUR",
        "Seller": {
            "Platform": "Shopify",
            "ShopName": "store",
            "ShopId": "x",
            "Id": "78537a6a-c8ec-4e7a-98a2-7f4b077c42cf",
            "Nick": null,
            "FirstName": null,
            "LastName": null,
            "FullName": "",
            "Email": "mail@gmail.com"
        },
        "Buyer": null,
        "UpdatedAt": null,
        "TaxRate1": 19.00,
        "TaxRate2": 7.00,
        "BillBeeOrderId": 79930247,
        "BillBeeParentOrderId": null,
        "VatId": null,
        "Tags": [],
        "ShipWeightKg": 0.1,
        "LanguageCode": null,
        "PaidAmount": null,
        "ShippingProfileId": null,
        "ShippingProviderId": null,
        "ShippingProviderProductId": null,
        "ShippingProviderName": null,
        "ShippingProviderProductName": null,
        "ShippingProfileName": null,
        "PaymentInstruction": null,
        "IsCancelationFor": null,
        "PaymentTransactionId": null,
        "DistributionCenter": null,
        "DeliverySourceCountryCode": null,
        "CustomInvoiceNote": null,
        "CustomerNumber": "260",
        "PaymentReference": "123",
        "ShippingServices": null,
        "Customer": {
            "Id": 123,
            "Name": "Name",
            "Email": "Mail@gmail.com",
            "Tel1": null,
            "Tel2": null,
            "Number": 260,
            "PriceGroupId": null,
            "LanguageId": null,
            "VatId": null,
            "Type": null
        },
        "History": [
            {
                "Created": "2019-10-31T09:13:00",
                "EventTypeName": "Auftrag eingelesen",
                "Text": "Der Auftrag wurde eingelesen",
                "EmployeeName": null,
                "TypeId": 0
            },
            {
                "Created": "2019-09-20T11:10:35",
                "EventTypeName": "Auftrag eingegangen",
                "Text": "Der Auftrag ist eingegangen",
                "EmployeeName": null,
                "TypeId": 86
            }
        ],
        "Payments": [],
        "LastModifiedAt": "2019-11-11T15:14:08.207"
    }, {...}}
```

how can I insert the values automatically to the different tables? I would need to get a list of all headers and insert it into different tables right?

I know the question is not very specific, but maybe someone can help me figure it out.

Comment: Hi @Philipp, Welcome to SO, I think you will need to learn of the web frameworks, like Django or flask or pyramid first to solve your problem. I am saying this because your project actually consists of many problems. For instance, firstly you will be required to parse the data, construct a complete DB, creating tables, adding data to the tables, perform data validation, etc. I would personally recommend Django to start with. I hope that in a way answered your question?

Comment: Thank you @VJMagar, I want to do this with Flask. That's a project I want to learn more about Python Web Developement. I need to learn more about Databases.. Thanks!